# Convert Excel form window to Google Sheets window

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

As you've probably found, there appears to be no equivalent way to add the following Excel form and associated VBA code to Google Sheets or Scripts or Forms:
[image: Excel VBA form]

Is there some add-in that can be used to pop up this image and its controls? This has to be used many times in an accounting sheet to categorize expenditures at tax time.

Comment: Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs. If you need further help, please show what you have tried to create the user interface using Google Apps Script and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks, Ruben. It looks like your hint about two-level custom menus will get me there. I'll try a three-level menu: (1) Main category (2) sub-category (3) action to take. I'll pull something together and post again "real soon now."

I was attempting to do it with multiple-dependent drop-down lists, but the things scroll out of the way when you have 1200+ records to process!

Comment: I think that a multi-level menu might require fewer coding but it's possible to achieve something similar to the screenshot by using the HtmlService (requires some basic web app development knowledge + the specifics of Google Apps Script.)

Comment: ...a post-script: I used the "Custom Menus" guidance above, and put in major, then minor category menus, with functions which write category information text into the selected cell. Interestingly, this also avoids the annoying "select the next lower cell" movement which can't be changed in spreadsheet settings. For multiple records, I make a single cell change with the custom menu, then <Ctrl-C> to copy, select a range of cells below there, and <Ctrl-V> to paste into 'em all.  ... a win-win-win situation! Many thanks, Rueben!

Answer (score 1):

It may not look exactly the same but I was able to construct a custom dialog in a short period of time to show how HTML service can be used to produce similar results.

First I construct an HTML template that contains the 2 combo boxes with multiple lines.

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_Test'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="left">
      <label for="expenseCategory">Expense Category</label><br>
      <select id="expenseCategory" size="10">
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <label for="expenseSubCategory">Expense Sub Category</label><br>
      <select id="expenseSubCategory" size="10">
    </select>
    </div>
    <?!= include('JS_Test'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then a CSS file to contain all my element formatting.

CSS_Test.html

```
<style>
  #expenseCategory {
    width: 90%;
  }
  #expenseSubCategory {
    width: 90%;
  }
  #left {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
  }
  #middle {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

And a javascript file for client side javascript.  I've simply hard coded some data to show how the select elements are filled in but this could just as easily be done using template scripting, or [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

```
<script>
  var expenses = [["A","1","2","3"],
                  ["B","4","5"],
                  ["C","6","7","8","9","10"]
  ];
  
  function expenseCategoryOnClick() {
    try {
      let expenseCategory = document.getElementById('expenseSubCategory');
      expenseCategory.options.length = 0;
      expenses[this.selectedIndex].forEach( (expense,index) => {
          if( index > 0 ) {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            let text = document.createTextNode(expense);
            option.appendChild(text);
            expenseCategory.appendChild(option);
          }
        } 
      );

    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in expenseCategoryOnClick: "+err)
    }
  }

  (function () {
      // load first expense
      let expenseCategory = document.getElementById('expenseCategory');
      expenseCategory.addEventListener("click",expenseCategoryOnClick);
      expenses.forEach( expense => {
          let option = document.createElement("option");
          let text = document.createTextNode(expense[0]);
          option.appendChild(text);
          expenseCategory.appendChild(option);
        }
      );
      expenseCategory = document.getElementById('expenseSubCategory');
      expenses[0].forEach( (expense,index) => {
          if( index > 0 ) {
            let option = document.createElement("option");
            let text = document.createTextNode(expense);
            option.appendChild(text);
            expenseCategory.appendChild(option);
          }
        } 
      );
    }
  )();
</script>
```

Then there is the server side code bound to a spreadsheet.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

// include(filename) required to include html files in the template
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  html = html.evaluate();
  html.setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}
```

The dialog looks like this.  Many more html elements can be added as needed.  This just shows the basics.  This may be more difficult than an wysiwig html editor but I find I have better control of the appearance and function of my pages this way.  Notice I clicked "C" and the sub category is filled in automatically.

[image]

Comment: Wow! ...looks complicated! ...but hey! it's higher level, and will probably come in handy. Once I get past tax season after next April, it looks like a good way for me to get into HTML, CSS, etc.L. Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: But it’s portable. It can be a bound custom dialog, stand-alone web app, or other web hosting site and use Google APIs. Not just Microsoft products.